# jquery set css background from href value

Tags: jquery, css, background, anchor

I have an image path that is being outputted to the href of an anchor tag. I'd like to set that image as the background for the anchor.

This is my snippet:

```
jQuery('.initialize a').css({
backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.href + ')'
,backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
,backgroundPosition: '0 0'
});
```

Which returns background-image: url(foo/undefined); on the anchor.

What am I doing wrong?

ETA:

```
jQuery('.initialize a').each(function() {
this.setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("href").replace(',\'', ''));
var href = this.getAttribute("href");
this.setAttribute("href", href.substr(0, href.length-14));
});
```

So I'm using the above to clean the output for the href attribute up a bit.

The suggested solution to my problem:

```
$(this).css({background-image: 'url(' + this.href + ')', ...});
```

should fit right in there. But I am not getting this to work, presumably due to the way my jQuery function is formatted. The $ is unavailable to me a at present. How can I fit this in?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery object of `this` to get href.

```
$(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. Look at the second line, is there a mistake in formatting?

Comment: @BiancaOortwijn The problem is that `this` in that context **doesn't** refer to the element being modified.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have a suggestion on how to proceed? I am not very good with jQuery.

Comment: `this` refers to current element in javascript but in jQuery it is `$(this)` .

Comment: @phazorRise Actually, `this` is more than likely going to refer to the `window` object. If the code is inside a jQuery attached event handler callback, then `this` will be the element that triggered the handler. It's very, very, very unlikely that `this` will actually be the correct element.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Correct.But if `this` is inside jQuery event handler, `this` can not be used to call jQuery methods though it refers to element that triggered it. WRT line - **It's very, very unlikely that this will actually be the correct element.**  `this` will always refer to element whose context it is in. It may not be correct or rather the element we want. I faced situations where I mistaken the context. Like in ajax success function I was trying to use this to element whose event handler actually made ajax call. I was wrong there. But at that time `this` referred to the success function.

Comment: Correct. I second Anthony Grist's method.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, `this` in the context that you're using it **doesn't** refer to the element that is being modified. You'll need to use an `.each()` loop to modify each element individually, so that you can access the attributes you want.

```
$('.initialize a').each(function() {
    $(this).css({background-image: 'url(' + this.href + ')', ...});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You must have noticed the my code formatting in this weird  jQuery no conflict mode. I have a feeling your code is correct, but doesn't fire still because of the $. Will report back.

Comment: Just replace `$` with `jQuery`, no?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use noConflict to use jQuery.
2. Put it in the background using jQuery's css function.
3. [JsFiddle sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/y2deA/)